# Changing data depending on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am getting data from a MySql database, although I don't know if there could be 1 or more hits from the query.
So, i am echoing something from the database, for example like this:

```
$code = "
<div style='position:absolute; top:100px'>
'$data'
</div>";
echo $code;
```

Now, since it is absolute; it is overlapping.
How could I change the 'top:' attribute if there are more results?(For every hit from the database, 'top:' would increment by some amount)

Comment: Why specify the `top` in the first place? Seems like this may be better achieved with `<ul><li></li></ul>` each of your elements as an `<li>`, then you use CSS to space them as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$top = 100; // top default value
$query = mysqli_query($link, 'SQL query is going to be here');

while (null !== ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)))
{
    $code = "
    <div style='position:absolute; top:".$top."px'>
    ".$data."
    </div>";
    echo $code;

    $top += 20; // increment top
}
```